# Group order 168 having a normal subgroup of order 4, then G has a normal subgroup of order 28.

Tags: abstract-algebra, sylow-theory

Prove that if G is a group of order 168 that has a normal subgroup of order
4, then G has a normal subgroup of order 28.

resolution:

P4 is the ordeme subgroup 4 and P7 the order subgroup 7. As P4 is normal in G we have P4P7 is a subgroup of G. And the order of P4P7 = 28. Applying the theorems of Sylow have to:
n7 = 1 and n2 = 1 or 7. How do I proceed to the accounts?

Answer (score 2):

Let $\;P_4\;$ be the normal subgroup of $\;G\;$, then $\;G/P_4\;$ is of order $\;42\;$ and such a group *always* has a normal subgroup of order $\;7\;$ which we can write as $\;H/P_4\;,\;\;P_4\le H\le G$ . Using the correspondence theorem, now just look at the subgroup $\;H\le G\;$  and answer:

i) Why is it normal in $\;G\;\;?$

ii) Why $\;|H|=28\;?$

Answer (score 1):

You want to use the fact that the product of two normal subgroups is itself normal. You already have a subgroup of order 4 that is normal, and you just showed (by Sylow) that there exists a normal subgroup of order 7, so their product is normal.

Comment: I don't think he showed the Sylow subgroup of order $\;7\;$ is normal **in** $\;G\;$...and I can't see how could he *directly* show that.

Comment: I was assuming his work to this point was correct, but you are right, you cannot deduce from Sylow that it is normal because $n_7=8$ is a possibility.

Comment: have the ability to n7 = 8 and I can not continue.